# TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got item {

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, image-recognition

I was using a custom code recognizing objects in real time using the webcam, but during the process of creating the labels this error appeared, I'm using python 3.7 and TensorFlow 1.15, which is wrong and there is an easier way to use real-time object recognition?

label map:

```
labels = [
    {'name':'1DIG', 'id':1},
    {'name':'2DIG', 'id':2}, 
    {'name':'3DIG', 'id':3}, 
    {'name':'4DIG', 'id':4},
]

with open(ANNOTATION_PATH + '\label_map.pbtxt', 'w') as f:
    for label in labels:
        f.write('item { \n')
        f.write('\tname:\'{}\'\n'.format(label['name']))
        f.write('\tid:{}\n'.format(label['id']))
        f.write('}\n')
```

code to tf record:

```
!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x {IMAGE_PATH + '/train'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/train.record'}
!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x{IMAGE_PATH + '/test'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/test.record'}
```

error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 62, in <module>
        label_map_dict = label_map_util.get_label_map_dict(label_map)
      File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py", line 164, in get_label_map_dict
        label_map = load_labelmap(label_map_path)
      File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py", line 133, in load_labelmap
        label_map_string = fid.read()
      File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 122, in read
        self._preread_check()
      File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 84, in _preread_check
        compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512)
      File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\util\compat.py", line 71, in as_bytes
        (bytes_or_text,))
    TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got item {
      name: "1DIG"
      id: 1
    }
    item {
      name: "2DIG"
      id: 2
    }
    item {
      name: "3DIG"

      id: 3
    }
   item {
      name: "4DIG"
      id: 4
    }
```

Comment: I have the same problem and this link is also worked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66665505/typeerror-expected-binary-or-unicode-string-got-item-error

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer in another link:

[TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got item error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66665505/typeerror-expected-binary-or-unicode-string-got-item-error)

[image: Check it out]

You might need to check the `xml_df.to_csv` location too

Answer (score 0):

You have a comma in the labels after the last item. Remove it